# json delivery of two parameters

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I'm building a star rating system using ajax & php. When user clicks, not only does the 'star' value need to be sent but also an identifier of the item being rated. How can I send both? I'm currently attempting echoing the id#. At the same time I'm trying to display the current rating from the SQL table, in real time, using PHP. Should I be doing this another way?

form with radio buttons

```
<div class="rating">
<form name="star" class="rating" method="post" action="getStarno(this.value, <?php echo $id; ?>)"
<legend><?php if(is_null($avgrate)){echo "Rate me!";} else {echo round($avgrate, 2);} ?> / 3</legend>
 <fieldset>
   <input type="radio"  name="Starno" value="1" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
   <input type="radio"  name="Starno" value="2" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
   <input type="radio"  name="Starno" value="3" onclick="this.form.submit()"/>
 </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
```

js

```
    function getStarno(int, $id)
     {
     if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
       }
     else
       {// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
       {
       if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
         {
         document.getElementById("rating").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
       }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","../rating.php?Starno="+int,true);

     xmlhttp.send();
     }
```

PHP

```
    <?php
    isset($_GET['id']);
    isset($_GET['starno']);
    $con=mysqli_connect ("","","","");
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO ratings (storyidr, rank, entry_date) 
            VALUES ('$_GET[id]','$_POST[starno]',now())");
    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [calling two js functions and don't print message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406753/calling-two-js-functions-and-dont-print-message)

Answer (score 1):

You could add hidden input field inside form, that would contain ID as value.